# Undefined reference using Allegro 5 with mingw-w64

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, allegro5

I'm trying to compile an Allegro 5 program on Windows 10 with mingw-w64.

- I already had installed mingw-w64. Output from `g++ --version` is:

  ```
  g++.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.1.0
  Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
  warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
  ```
- I downloaded windows binaries for Allegro 5 from https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/releases (File: `allegro-x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-8.2.1-posix-seh-static-5.2.5.0.zip`) and unzipped the file into `C:/allegro5` so now I have `C:/allegro5/bin`, `C:/allegro5/include`, `C:/allegro5/lib`.
- A small test program:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <allegro5/allegro.h>

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
     al_init();
     return 0;
  }
  ```
- And finally the command I run to compile: `g++ test.cpp -I"C:/allegro5/include" -L"C:/allegro5/lib" -lallegro` (There is a lib file called `liballegro.dll.a` under `C:/allegro5/lib`)

But there are some problems while linking:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccg5z97Y.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `al_install_system'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

A) What may be the reason for this ?

B) What should I do to compile in a static way ? Is changing `-lallegro` to `-lallegro-static` enough ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
g++.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.1.0
```

is one of the the 32-bit GCC variants provided by MinGW-W64. You are attempting to link the
32-bit code it generates with the 64-bit libraries provided in:

```
allegro-x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-8.2.1-posix-seh-static-5.2.5.0.zip
```

which will not work. Replace your compiler with the appropriate 64-bit variant [x86_64-posix-seh](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/)

Comment: I took my time to learn what all of this version values mean. Thank you